# How can I build this query to compare a id with two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: query logic]

I have drawn this image to explain what I need

> 1.to compare a user_id with the user_id's in two different tables
>
> 2.the corresponding ref_global_id from both the tables are then matched to a events table
>
> 3.matching global_id's from the events table are then arranged in ascending order.

Comment: the global ids in the last table in your picture are not arranged in ascending order. i am confused

Comment: Do you know the user_id beforehand, or does the query have to figure it out? If you do know the user_id, you could just to do a select on table1 and table2, union them and then join with your events table.

Comment: @Alp sorry for that, but problem is not with Ascending or Descending

Comment: @JvdBerg thanx man, at least somebody appreciated my drawing efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
    SELECT e.global_id, e.event_time
    FROM (SELECT * FROM table1
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM table2) x inner join
          event_table e ON e.global_id = x.ref_global_id
    WHERE x.[user_id] = 121
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.global_id, e.event_time
FROM events_table e
JOIN table1 t1 on e.global_id = t1.ref_global_id
JOIN table2 t2 on e.global_id = t2.ref_global_id
WHERE t1.user_id = 121 AND t2.user_id = 121
ORDER BY e.event_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select global_id, event_time from event left join table1 on event.global_id = table1.ref_global_id AND table1.user_id = 121 left join table2 on event.global_id = table2.ref_global_id AND table2.user_id = 121
```

Comment: LEFT join make this query no sense. Because ALL rows from events table will be displayed.